# Merging two Dataframes with different levels and move one level of hierarchical row index to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two dataframes I want to merge:

The first one:

```
In:   array = [['RMP1','RMP1','RMP1','Coop','Coop','Coop','RMP2','RMP2','RMP2'],
               ['1. Varazdin','5.Vipap','11. Brno','1.Varazdin','5.Vipap','11. Brno','1.Varazdin','5.Vipap','11. Brno']]

      tuples = list(zip(*array))
      index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['project', 'sample'])

      df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(9*7).reshape(9,7),
                           index=index,
                           columns=['volume_filtered','filtration[date]','DNA_extract[µL]','DNA_isolation[Date]','IC','Sul1','qnrS'])
```

And the second one:

```
 df2:
                                   count    mean    std min 25% 50% 75% max
project     sample     gene 
                       IC            1        2      3   4   5   6   7   8
        1. Varazdin    Sul1          9        10     11  12  13  14  15  16
                       qnrS          17       18     19  20  21  22  23  24  
                       IC
        2. Amstetten   Sul1                            .
                       qnrS                            .
                       IC                              .
Coop    3.Cluj         Sul1                            .
.                      qnrS                            .
.                                                      .
.                      IC                              .
        1. Varazdin    Sul1                            .
                       qnrS                            .
                       IC
        2. Amstetten   Sul1
                       qnrS
                       IC
RMP1    3.Cluj         Sul1
                       qnrS
.
.
.
```

I joined them using:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2.unstack(), on=['project','sample'])
```

And this gets me a dataframe (df3) with no hierarchical indexing. I can now define the index with:

```
df3.set_index(['project','sample'], inplace=True)
```

and it works fine.

What I want to do now is keep the row index of df1 but add a MultiIndex to the columns so that the values from df2 will be stored under the columns 'IC', 'Sul1' and 'qnrS' . I would like these columns to be summarized under the name `'genes'`.

EDIT:

dictionary of df2:

```
{'25%': project  sample             gene
Coop     1. Varazdin        IC         895.425000
                            Sul1    306300.000000
                            qnrS       842.400000
         10. Sabac          IC         607.250000
                            Sul1    172875.000000
                            qnrS     20135.000000
         11. Brno           IC         355.050000
                            Sul1      3202.750000
                            qnrS         3.261472
         12. Zagreb         IC         547.400000
                            Sul1     21332.500000
                            qnrS         0.005167
         2. Amstetten       IC          51.267500
                            Sul1       551.325000
                            qnrS              NaN
         3. Cluj            IC         885.000000
                            Sul1      9035.800250
                            qnrS         6.225000
         4. Augsburg        IC         258.775000
                            Sul1       778.625000
                            qnrS         0.041505
         5. Vipap           IC         220.900000
                            Sul1      1196.000000
                            qnrS         0.370600
         6. Budapest        IC         389.875000
                            Sul1      4796.750000
                            qnrS        45.760000
         7.Ljubljana        IC         439.875000
                            Sul1      2398.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
         8. Bukarest        IC         876.050000
                            Sul1    259150.000000
                            qnrS       699.925000
         9. Zilina          IC         314.875000
                            Sul1      1081.250000
                            qnrS              NaN
RdG2     Communal WW        IC         631.950000
                            Sul1    320950.000000
                            qnrS        70.592500
         H1                 IC          35.400000
                            Sul1    104250.000000
                            qnrS         4.773750
         H4                 IC         782.200000
                            Sul1    816500.000000
                            qnrS        37.090000
         Pharm.-Inlet       IC           0.835000
                            Sul1     72595.000000
                            qnrS         0.052330
         Pharm.1- MBR       IC         662.950000
                            Sul1       112.160000
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.2-Ozone      IC         625.450000
                            Sul1      1250.500000
                            qnrS         4.416000
         Pharm.3-GAC        IC        1089.500000
                            Sul1      1881.500000
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.4-UV/Outlet  IC         725.900000
                            Sul1       278.500000
                            qnrS              NaN
         WWTP Inlet 24h     IC         431.000000
                            Sul1    180822.500000
                            qnrS        23.580000
         WWTP Outlet 24h    IC         437.450000
                            Sul1    411400.000000
                            qnrS       215.000000
Name: 25%, dtype: float64,
 '50%': project  sample             gene
Coop     1. Varazdin        IC         897.150000
                            Sul1    312900.000000
                            qnrS       842.400000
         10. Sabac          IC         612.600000
                            Sul1    176850.000000
                            qnrS     20610.000000
         11. Brno           IC         356.700000
                            Sul1      3262.500000
                            qnrS         6.484315
         12. Zagreb         IC         568.800000
                            Sul1     22215.000000
                            qnrS         0.005167
         2. Amstetten       IC          57.915000
                            Sul1       562.450000
                            qnrS              NaN
         3. Cluj            IC         885.000000
                            Sul1     18070.533500
                            qnrS         6.225000
         4. Augsburg        IC         266.650000
                            Sul1       801.950000
                            qnrS         0.050550
         5. Vipap           IC         222.600000
                            Sul1      1203.000000
                            qnrS         0.370600
         6. Budapest        IC         402.150000
                            Sul1      4799.500000
                            qnrS        46.790000
         7.Ljubljana        IC         441.250000
                            Sul1      2482.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
         8. Bukarest        IC         898.800000
                            Sul1    268500.000000
                            qnrS       771.350000
         9. Zilina          IC         321.550000
                            Sul1      1099.500000
                            qnrS              NaN
RdG2     Communal WW        IC         689.500000
                            Sul1    342700.000000
                            qnrS        77.735000
         H1                 IC          40.040000
                            Sul1    105600.000000
                            qnrS         5.170500
         H4                 IC         789.500000
                            Sul1    864700.000000
                            qnrS        42.190000
         Pharm.-Inlet       IC           1.399000
                            Sul1     73860.000000
                            qnrS         0.063520
         Pharm.1- MBR       IC         847.200000
                            Sul1       144.900000
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.2-Ozone      IC         689.200000
                            Sul1      1265.000000
                            qnrS         4.416000
         Pharm.3-GAC        IC        1097.000000
                            Sul1      1921.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.4-UV/Outlet  IC         740.400000
                            Sul1       290.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
         WWTP Inlet 24h     IC         463.700000
                            Sul1    360300.000000
                            qnrS        23.580000
         WWTP Outlet 24h    IC         495.600000
                            Sul1    435500.000000
                            qnrS       216.900000
Name: 50%, dtype: float64,
 '75%': project  sample             gene
Coop     1. Varazdin        IC         898.875000
                            Sul1    319500.000000
                            qnrS       842.400000
         10. Sabac          IC         617.950000
                            Sul1    180825.000000
                            qnrS     21085.000000
         11. Brno           IC         358.350000
                            Sul1      3322.250000
                            qnrS         9.707157
         12. Zagreb         IC         590.200000
                            Sul1     23097.500000
                            qnrS         0.005167
         2. Amstetten       IC          64.562500
                            Sul1       573.575000
                            qnrS              NaN
         3. Cluj            IC         885.000000
                            Sul1     27105.266750
                            qnrS         6.225000
         4. Augsburg        IC         274.525000
                            Sul1       825.275000
                            qnrS         0.059595
         5. Vipap           IC         224.300000
                            Sul1      1210.000000
                            qnrS         0.370600
         6. Budapest        IC         414.425000
                            Sul1      4802.250000
                            qnrS        47.820000
         7.Ljubljana        IC         442.625000
                            Sul1      2566.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
         8. Bukarest        IC         921.550000
                            Sul1    277850.000000
                            qnrS       842.775000
         9. Zilina          IC         328.225000
                            Sul1      1117.750000
                            qnrS              NaN
RdG2     Communal WW        IC         704.350000
                            Sul1    349850.000000
                            qnrS        84.877500
         H1                 IC          41.645000
                            Sul1    108950.000000
                            qnrS         5.567250
         H4                 IC         824.600000
                            Sul1    876450.000000
                            qnrS        46.760000
         Pharm.-Inlet       IC           1.963000
                            Sul1     75290.000000
                            qnrS         0.106010
         Pharm.1- MBR       IC         896.800000
                            Sul1       147.100000
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.2-Ozone      IC         719.700000
                            Sul1    238832.500000
                            qnrS         4.416000
         Pharm.3-GAC        IC        1126.500000
                            Sul1      1980.500000
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.4-UV/Outlet  IC         747.900000
                            Sul1       305.700000
                            qnrS              NaN
         WWTP Inlet 24h     IC         618.450000
                            Sul1    404100.000000
                            qnrS        23.580000
         WWTP Outlet 24h    IC         503.300000
                            Sul1    440200.000000
                            qnrS       220.400000
Name: 75%, dtype: float64,
 'count': project  sample             gene
Coop     1. Varazdin        IC      2.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    1.0
         10. Sabac          IC      2.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    2.0
         11. Brno           IC      2.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    2.0
         12. Zagreb         IC      2.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    1.0
         2. Amstetten       IC      2.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    0.0
         3. Cluj            IC      1.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    1.0
         4. Augsburg        IC      2.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    2.0
         5. Vipap           IC      2.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    1.0
         6. Budapest        IC      2.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    2.0
         7.Ljubljana        IC      2.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    0.0
         8. Bukarest        IC      2.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    2.0
         9. Zilina          IC      2.0
                            Sul1    2.0
                            qnrS    0.0
RdG2     Communal WW        IC      3.0
                            Sul1    3.0
                            qnrS    2.0
         H1                 IC      3.0
                            Sul1    3.0
                            qnrS    2.0
         H4                 IC      3.0
                            Sul1    3.0
                            qnrS    3.0
         Pharm.-Inlet       IC      2.0
                            Sul1    3.0
                            qnrS    3.0
         Pharm.1- MBR       IC      3.0
                            Sul1    3.0
                            qnrS    0.0
         Pharm.2-Ozone      IC      3.0
                            Sul1    3.0
                            qnrS    1.0
         Pharm.3-GAC        IC      3.0
                            Sul1    3.0
                            qnrS    0.0
         Pharm.4-UV/Outlet  IC      3.0
                            Sul1    3.0
                            qnrS    0.0
         WWTP Inlet 24h     IC      3.0
                            Sul1    3.0
                            qnrS    1.0
         WWTP Outlet 24h    IC      3.0
                            Sul1    3.0
                            qnrS    3.0
Name: count, dtype: float64,
 'max': project  sample             gene
Coop     1. Varazdin        IC         900.600000
                            Sul1    326100.000000
                            qnrS       842.400000
         10. Sabac          IC         623.300000
                            Sul1    184800.000000
                            qnrS     21560.000000
         11. Brno           IC         360.000000
                            Sul1      3382.000000
                            qnrS        12.930000
         12. Zagreb         IC         611.600000
                            Sul1     23980.000000
                            qnrS         0.005167
         2. Amstetten       IC          71.210000
                            Sul1       584.700000
                            qnrS              NaN
         3. Cluj            IC         885.000000
                            Sul1     36140.000000
                            qnrS         6.225000
         4. Augsburg        IC         282.400000
                            Sul1       848.600000
                            qnrS         0.068640
         5. Vipap           IC         226.000000
                            Sul1      1217.000000
                            qnrS         0.370600
         6. Budapest        IC         426.700000
                            Sul1      4805.000000
                            qnrS        48.850000
         7.Ljubljana        IC         444.000000
                            Sul1      2650.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
         8. Bukarest        IC         944.300000
                            Sul1    287200.000000
                            qnrS       914.200000
         9. Zilina          IC         334.900000
                            Sul1      1136.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
RdG2     Communal WW        IC         719.200000
                            Sul1    357000.000000
                            qnrS        92.020000
         H1                 IC          43.250000
                            Sul1    112300.000000
                            qnrS         5.964000
         H4                 IC         859.700000
                            Sul1    888200.000000
                            qnrS        51.330000
         Pharm.-Inlet       IC           2.527000
                            Sul1     76720.000000
                            qnrS         0.148500
         Pharm.1- MBR       IC         946.400000
                            Sul1       149.300000
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.2-Ozone      IC         750.200000
                            Sul1    476400.000000
                            qnrS         4.416000
         Pharm.3-GAC        IC        1156.000000
                            Sul1      2040.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.4-UV/Outlet  IC         755.400000
                            Sul1       321.400000
                            qnrS              NaN
         WWTP Inlet 24h     IC         773.200000
                            Sul1    447900.000000
                            qnrS        23.580000
         WWTP Outlet 24h    IC         511.000000
                            Sul1    444900.000000
                            qnrS       223.900000
Name: max, dtype: float64,
 'mean': project  sample             gene
Coop     1. Varazdin        IC         897.150000
                            Sul1    312900.000000
                            qnrS       842.400000
         10. Sabac          IC         612.600000
                            Sul1    176850.000000
                            qnrS     20610.000000
         11. Brno           IC         356.700000
                            Sul1      3262.500000
                            qnrS         6.484315
         12. Zagreb         IC         568.800000
                            Sul1     22215.000000
                            qnrS         0.005167
         2. Amstetten       IC          57.915000
                            Sul1       562.450000
                            qnrS              NaN
         3. Cluj            IC         885.000000
                            Sul1     18070.533500
                            qnrS         6.225000
         4. Augsburg        IC         266.650000
                            Sul1       801.950000
                            qnrS         0.050550
         5. Vipap           IC         222.600000
                            Sul1      1203.000000
                            qnrS         0.370600
         6. Budapest        IC         402.150000
                            Sul1      4799.500000
                            qnrS        46.790000
         7.Ljubljana        IC         441.250000
                            Sul1      2482.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
         8. Bukarest        IC         898.800000
                            Sul1    268500.000000
                            qnrS       771.350000
         9. Zilina          IC         321.550000
                            Sul1      1099.500000
                            qnrS              NaN
RdG2     Communal WW        IC         661.033333
                            Sul1    332966.666667
                            qnrS        77.735000
         H1                 IC          38.016667
                            Sul1    106933.333333
                            qnrS         5.170500
         H4                 IC         808.033333
                            Sul1    840400.000000
                            qnrS        41.836667
         Pharm.-Inlet       IC           1.399000
                            Sul1     73970.000000
                            qnrS         0.084387
         Pharm.1- MBR       IC         757.433333
                            Sul1       124.540000
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.2-Ozone      IC         667.033333
                            Sul1    159633.666667
                            qnrS         4.416000
         Pharm.3-GAC        IC        1111.666667
                            Sul1      1934.333333
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.4-UV/Outlet  IC         735.733333
                            Sul1       292.800000
                            qnrS              NaN
         WWTP Inlet 24h     IC         545.066667
                            Sul1    269848.333333
                            qnrS        23.580000
         WWTP Outlet 24h    IC         461.966667
                            Sul1    422566.666667
                            qnrS       217.966667
Name: mean, dtype: float64,
 'min': project  sample             gene
Coop     1. Varazdin        IC         893.700000
                            Sul1    299700.000000
                            qnrS       842.400000
         10. Sabac          IC         601.900000
                            Sul1    168900.000000
                            qnrS     19660.000000
         11. Brno           IC         353.400000
                            Sul1      3143.000000
                            qnrS         0.038630
         12. Zagreb         IC         526.000000
                            Sul1     20450.000000
                            qnrS         0.005167
         2. Amstetten       IC          44.620000
                            Sul1       540.200000
                            qnrS              NaN
         3. Cluj            IC         885.000000
                            Sul1         1.067000
                            qnrS         6.225000
         4. Augsburg        IC         250.900000
                            Sul1       755.300000
                            qnrS         0.032460
         5. Vipap           IC         219.200000
                            Sul1      1189.000000
                            qnrS         0.370600
         6. Budapest        IC         377.600000
                            Sul1      4794.000000
                            qnrS        44.730000
         7.Ljubljana        IC         438.500000
                            Sul1      2314.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
         8. Bukarest        IC         853.300000
                            Sul1    249800.000000
                            qnrS       628.500000
         9. Zilina          IC         308.200000
                            Sul1      1063.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
RdG2     Communal WW        IC         574.400000
                            Sul1    299200.000000
                            qnrS        63.450000
         H1                 IC          30.760000
                            Sul1    102900.000000
                            qnrS         4.377000
         H4                 IC         774.900000
                            Sul1    768300.000000
                            qnrS        31.990000
         Pharm.-Inlet       IC           0.271000
                            Sul1     71330.000000
                            qnrS         0.041140
         Pharm.1- MBR       IC         478.700000
                            Sul1        79.420000
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.2-Ozone      IC         561.700000
                            Sul1      1236.000000
                            qnrS         4.416000
         Pharm.3-GAC        IC        1082.000000
                            Sul1      1842.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
         Pharm.4-UV/Outlet  IC         711.400000
                            Sul1       267.000000
                            qnrS              NaN
         WWTP Inlet 24h     IC         398.300000
                            Sul1      1345.000000
                            qnrS        23.580000
         WWTP Outlet 24h    IC         379.300000
                            Sul1    387300.000000
                            qnrS       213.100000
Name: min, dtype: float64,
 'std': project  sample             gene
Coop     1. Varazdin        IC           4.879037
                            Sul1     18667.619023
                            qnrS              NaN
         10. Sabac          IC          15.132085
                            Sul1     11242.997821
                            qnrS      1343.502884
         11. Brno           IC           4.666905
                            Sul1       168.998521
                            qnrS         9.115575
         12. Zagreb         IC          60.528340
                            Sul1      2496.086938
                            qnrS              NaN

Name: std, dtype: float64}
```

Comment: Could you reformat array and df2 to present it more readable (e.g. presenting source list / dictionary from which you created df2)?

Comment: I have df2 on a Jupyter Notebook but when I try to copy and paste it into the question, it gets all messed up. I'm going to try again

Comment: If you deliver with a dictionary / list that makes up the "df2" it could help me in finding solution.

Comment: @artona I added a dictionary that makes up df2. I had to delete some of the last rows because otherwise it would have been too long to post

Comment: Unfortunately you have not provided with Python dictionary but with DataFrame (however it does not work either). By a dictionary or a list I mean something like your variable named "array".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I think you need convert last level `gene` to `column`, so is possible `join`:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2.reset_index('gene'))
```

Or:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2.reset_index('gene'), on=['project','sample'])
```

Comment: df3 = df1.join(df2.reset_index('gene'), on = ['project','sample'])
df3.set_index(['project','sample','gene'])   -> I reset the index after and it looked just the way I wanted it to